# Implement a CompareTo in Java

Tags: java, comparable

I have an class PersonQ

```
public class PersonQ {
    Queue <Person> queue;
    int Rows;

    public PersonQ(int r){
        queue = new PriorityQueue<Person>(); 
        Rows = r; 
    }

    //Also I have getters and setters and a method to fill randomly with Random
}
```

And now

```
public class Person implements Comparable <Person> {
    String name; 
    int id; 
    double salary; 
    int position;

    public Person(String pN, int pID, double pSal, int pPos) {
        this.name = pN; 
        this.id = pID; 
        this.salary= pSal; 
        position=pPos;
    }

//Also I have getters and setters 

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person other) {
        /*There I don't know how to make my statements because at the moment when I remove an element 
        it sorts wrong; Look, when I add 5 elements randomly it gets its proper position: 1, 2, 3, 4 
        and the last 5 when I use the method poll() it removes the element with position 1 but the 
        next step is that it sorts in a weird way, for example sometimes it starts with the element 
        with position 5, 4, 2 or 3 it occurs randomly and I want to see it in their proper order by its position */
    }
}
```

I want to show my Queue in this order after remove an element, If I remove an element with position 1, then the rest of them must appear like this: 2,3,4,5 and if I remove another it has to appear: 3,4,5 and so on. I tried with "`Integer.compare(this.position, other.position);`"
And is the same

Comment: Are you trying to compare by id or something else?

Comment: How are you verifying that your order is wrong?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: And also imp the formatting of your question. Indentation matters, and that lengthy comment inside your code is close to unreadable on mobile devices.

Comment: Question is unclear because you've not said what you are supposed to be comparing. Position is not a meaningful property of any element - Does a Person need to know its  own `position`?

Comment: Please loop over the queue in that way: `while(!queue.isEmpty()){
  Person p = queue.poll();
}`

Comment: guys I made a Overview of everything, and I'm sure it shows wrong because I saw it in the debug

Comment: In debug my queue it's fine when I add elements, that's why I add an additional value called position to prove it, so when I use a method like remove() or poll() my queue itself in debug mode change everything. For example an queue made by 5 elements each element has it's position: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, so when I delete one element obviously it'll delete the head from the queue and then my new queue must has this order: 2, 3, 4, 5 (Start with 2 instead of another position selected randomly). This is my whole question how to keep the order by my var position.

Comment: I use Iterator only to show info but correct me if I'm wrong is there any method or something to order my queue, because I don't think the fact that after remove an element with a method the new queue will have random positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `java.util.PriorityQueue`, your class need to implement `Comparable` or specify `Comparator` when create an instance of `PriorityQueue`. The elements in queue will be sorted from low value to high value, the element will be evaluated by `Comparator.compare` or `Comparable.compareTo` method.

In your case, your class `Person` implements `Comparable<Person>`, you have to determine the order of `Person`. This implementation will make the elements order by `position`:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person other) {
    return position - other.position;
}
```

When you use `PriorityQueue.poll()`, it will give you the least value element.

**Note**: `java.util.PriorityQueue` and its iterator implement all of the optional methods of the `Collection` and `Iterator` interfaces. The `Iterator` provided in method `iterator()` is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())` (From Java doc)

Comment: Nice, You were close, but with this:
return position - other.position; 
It does well with the first and last one but in the middle it still doing wrong, but don't worry I did it: return other.position -position; this did it backwards

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to know for sure, but I'm guessing that you're using the `Iterator` returned by the `PriorityQueue.iterator()` method to verify the ordering of your queue.

Now, the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator--) of that method clearly states (emphasis mine):

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator **does
>   not return the elements in any particular order**.

Comment: Yes, I use all that stuff but in debug it shows the wrong position

Comment: In debug my queue it's fine when I add elements, that's why I add an additional value called position to prove it, so when I use a method like remove() or poll() my queue itself in debug mode change everything. For example an queue made by 5 elements each element has it's position: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, so when I delete one element obviously it'll delete the head from the queue and then my new queue must has this order: 2, 3, 4, 5 (Start with 2 instead of another position selected randomly). This is my whole question how to keep the order by var position.